# animate activity start in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, onclicklistener

I need to animate my `Activity` when it starts up. The Activity is started from a `BaseAdapter` class. I tried using `overridePendingTransition()` but I can't seem to use that in the on click event. How can I over come this?

```
holder.userpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(" ", " value " + obj.get(position).get_post_id());
        Intent appInfo = new Intent("android.intent.action.Profile");
        appInfo.putExtra("pk", obj.get(position).get_foodie_id());

        context.startActivity(appInfo);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.full_side_up,0); // cant use this
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the `Context` as:

```
context.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.full_side_up,0);
```

Or you can use the transition in `onResume` method inside the new `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.full_side_up,0);
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

`overridePendingTransition` is a method of the `Activity` class. You would have to hold a reference to an activity.

An alternative would be specifying your listener in XML using `onClick` attribute as follows:

```
<ImageView
    id="@+id/user_pic"
    ...
    onClick="onClickUserPic" />
```

Then you create method `onClickUserPic(View)` inside your activity (which contains the ListView filled by your adapter class):

```
public void onClickUserPic(View view) {
  int position = (Integer)view.getTag(); // here is stored position in list

  Log.d(" ", " value " + obj.get(position).get_post_id());
  Intent appInfo = new Intent("android.intent.action.Profile");
  appInfo.putExtra("pk", obj.get(position).get_foodie_id());

  context.startActivity(appInfo);
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.full_side_up,0);
}
```

Note that this method has to be inside this and any other activity which contains the clickable image view. If it weren't, you would get a `NoSuchMethodException` on click.

Finally add this line to your adapter:

```
holder.userpic.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position)); // save position for reference
```

Also make sure that you have access to `obj` from inside the activity.